# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tf.sequential is not a function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

Well, practically what I want to do is test tensorFlow.js in a chrome extension, so I made a machine learning application using tensorFlow.js on a web page, to then implement it in an extension.

but this error appears when I press the icon of my extension:
[image]

I believe it is as if It were not recognizing the syntax of tensorFlow.js, since **tf.sequential ();** is already a ready function of the tfjs library.

Could someone help me with this problem?

**Here are the codes:**

Manisfest.json:

```
{
"name":"Teste implementacao extension",
"version":"1.0",
"description":"NULL for While",
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"index.html"
},

"manifest_version":2,
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js 'sha256-AJlm0gxYKWeBb5choQtViwczPIiEm/8RF2tRQOdGGR4='; object-src 'self'"
```

}

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="output_field">
    
</div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
    /*

    Rede neural com javascript no navegador.
    e treinou ela para prever uma regressão linear.

*/

async function learnLinear(){
    //alert("dsds");
        const model  = tf.sequential();
        model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
        model.compile({
            loss: 'meanSquaredError',
            optimizer: 'sgd'
        });
        const xs = tf.tensor2d([-1,0,1,2,3,4], [6,1]);
        const ys = tf.tensor2d([-3,-1,1,3,5,7], [6,1]);
        //treinando o modelo
        await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100});//tempo pra corrigir os erros
        //valor inicial: 250
        document.getElementById('output_field').innerText =
            model.predict(tf.tensor2d([20], [1,1])); 
}

learnLinear();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript import syntax in your JavaScript code snippet probably won't work with vanilla node. You should try either babel-node (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) or using the require() syntax:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
```